# Filter by column alias (firebird sql)

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I made a UDF called DistanceMeters which returns the distance between two coordinates as an integer. Now I want to use it to filter the results, for example,

```
SELECT DistanceMeters("Latitude_C_", "Longitude_C_", 44.894115, -123.031717) as dis 
FROM CURR_LOCATION where dis < 5000 ORDER by dis
```

The problems is that I can't refer to the column alias in the where condition:

```
SQL error code = -206
Column unknown
DIS
```

This will work:

```
SELECT * FROM CURR_LOCATION where DistanceMeters("Latitude_C_", "Longitude_C_", 44.894115, -123.031717) < 5000
```

but I want to show the distance as a result too.

Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use derived table:

```
SELECT dis FROM
  (SELECT DistanceMeters("Latitude_C_", "Longitude_C_", 44.894115, -123.031717) as dis 
   FROM CURR_LOCATION)
WHERE dis < 5000 ORDER BY dis
```